# How to switch tabs by clicking on tab with out using next button in vuejs vue-form-wizard?

Tags: vue.js

I am creating tabs in vuejs using vue-form-wizard. I am not able to navigate first tab to second or third tab directly clicking on the tab first time. Once we navigate all tabs by clicking on next button, then we are able to move any tab by selecting the tab directly without using next button. In my case I am going to hide next button. If I hide this button, how can I navigate other tabs?
Please find my code below.

https://jsfiddle.net/bt5dhqtf/1241/

```
<div id="app">
<div>
        <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete" 
                      shape="square"
                      layout="vertical"
                      steps-classes="steps-size"
                      color="#3498db">
            <tab-content title="Personal details"
                         icon="ti-user" v-if="t2=='y'">
              My first tab content
            </tab-content>
            <tab-content title="Additional Info"
                         icon="ti-settings" v-if="t3=='y'">
              My second tab content
            </tab-content>
            <tab-content title="Last step"
                         icon="ti-check">
              Yuhuuu! This seems pretty damn simple
            </tab-content>
        </form-wizard>
 </div>
</div>

Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data(){return{
 t1:'y',
 t2:'y',
 t3:'y',
 }

 },
 created:{
 //this.t2='y',
 },
 methods: {
  onComplete: function(){
      alert('Yay. Done!');
   }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use nextTab method

add ref at wizard component:
`<form-wizard ref="wizard"...`

> ```
> <tab-content title="Additional Info" icon="ti-settings">
> ```

```
    My second tab content
    <button @click="goNext">
        go next
    </button>
</tab-content>

methods:
    goNext() {
        //alert(this.$refs.wizard.activeTabIndex);
        this.$refs.wizard.nextTab();
    },
```

Comment: Thank you I was wondering why I couldn't trigger the nextTab from content, this worked for me, was missing the wizard ref.

Comment: Thankyou very much, this example should be on their website